# Google Forms: Multiple Parties Editing a Single Response

Tags: google-forms

I have a google form with 5 page breaks, each navigating to a different section of a customer's profile.

I have created the necessary edit.urls, however, when section 2 is edited, it erases the previously saved section 1 data - even though that information was on a separate page and untouched.

Any clarification on how to solve this dilemma would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Google Forms are not intended for respondents collaboration. The answers to each question will be saved until the user press the submit button. This will save all the answers that user had set and will not update the form that other user has opened before. To get the las answers, the user should open the form after the last changes were submitted.

If you need that several users work together filling different pages, instead of using a Google Form, consider to use a Google Docs document, spreadsheet or presentation. You or your respondents should make a copy or use publish the document as a template.

It's worth to say that the help article about collaborating with forms is for editing the form. From [Share your form with collaborators - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917111?hl=en&ref_topic=6063584)

> If you're working on a form and would like to share it with a
>   collaborator, click the **File** and select **Add collaborators...**. Then,
>   from the "Sharing settings" dialog, you can specify individual
>   collaborators with whom you'd like to share your form for editing. To
>   add a collaborator, begin typing his or her name in the "Invite
>   people" text box.
>
> When you're working with a collaborator on a form, each of you can
>   edit one input field at a time. For example, your collaborator can
>   edit the text of a question while you edit the help text of that same
>   question.